# nested ngfor equivalent in react native

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-native

I'm trying to create a list of buttons depending on a two dimensional array of data I did it in angular 2 with nested ngfor but I can't do it in react native so what would be the equivalent of this:

```
<table >
    <tr *ngFor="let tile of tiles; let i = index ">
        <td *ngFor="let button of tile; let j = index">
          <button type="button" (click)="click(i,j,$event.target)"class="btn-group-lg"> X</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also I would like to know how to use an index because I have to set an action to the button index related to the array

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this freehand, but it should at least get you in the right direction (I'm assuming tiles is a prop, if not change to whatever source it is coming from).

```
<table >
  {this.props.tiles.map((tile, i) => (
    <tr>
      {tile.map((button, j) => (
        <td>
          <button type="button" onClick={(event) => click(i,j,event.target)} class="btn-group-lg"> X</button>
        </td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```